# Proof regarding convex sets

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

A set of points is said to be convex provided that every pair of points in the set can be joined by a line segment that lies entirely within the set.

Show that, if $ | ∇f(x)| ≤ M \space \space \forall x $ in some convex set Ω, then:

$ |f(x_1) − f(x_2)| ≤ M|x_1 − x_2| $

How would I approach this question. I don't need a full proof initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Omega$ be the line segment joining $x_1,x_2$, $\gamma(t)=tx_2+(1-t)x_1$. Then $$\begin{align}|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|&=|f(\gamma(0))-f(\gamma(1))|\\&=|\nabla(f\circ\gamma)(c)|\\&=|(\nabla f)(\gamma(c))\circ \gamma'(c)|\\&\leq|\nabla f||\gamma'(c)|\\&\leq M|\gamma'(c)|\\&=M|x_1-x_2|.\end{align}$$